# Can applications predinstalled in system/priv-app be updated via Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, custom-roms, 7.0-nougat, launcher, application-autoupdate

we're trying to make our custom launcher default one in our phone. Since it needs system level permissions (placing widgets) we placed it in system/priv-app, and it finally works ok. Problem is that it is not updateing with new version from Play Store. - we're getting error 505 after downloading update, on start of install process

thank you in advance!
br
Y

Comment: To close-voters: though Yuray asks for installing his own app that way, this is not a development question but perfectly on-topic here. Us power users sometimes "convert" regular apps into system apps as well, and still want them updated :) Nice side-effect is e.g. the app surviving a factory-reset (though its data does not).

Comment: What permissions did you give it after placing in`/system/priv-app`? Make sure it's `644`. Also, have you placed the apk in a directory having name as the app name?

Comment: I met the same problem. The message is "Error -505 while installing com.mycompany.mypackage: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.mycompany.mypackage signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!". Although the signatures do match. @Yuray have you solved the problem?

Answer (score 4):

If the "pre-installed app" uses the same signature as the one on Google Play, it of course can be updated that way – same as e.g. Google Maps and other pre-installed stuff is.

Note that, however, those updates would not be integrated in the ROM, but go into user-space – "overlaying" the pre-installed version. This gives users the advantage of being able to "uninstall updates", but at the cost of "double space" (the original APK remains in `/system` – not that they could use that space otherwise, though).

Comment: we use same signature, if we weren't system could not detect existing update at first place. If we move launcher in regular apps folder, update goes as expected.

Comment: @Yuray in that case I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Google Play is re-signing my package. This used to cause a signatures mismatch. The solution is to install to /system/priv-app/ an apk downloaded from GP (that has been already re-signed).